# libgdx - exception while creating selectbox

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I have a problem while creating selectbox on libgdx.

```
Skin.add("button", new Texture("data/menu/button.png"));
[...]    
SelectBoxStyle selectboxstyle = new SelectBoxStyle();

selectboxstyle.font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/menufont.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/menufont.png"), false);`

selectboxstyle.background = Skin.getDrawable("button");

SelectBox dropdown = new SelectBox(new String[] {"item1", "item2"}, selectboxstyle);
```

The last line throw exception:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.setItems(SelectBox.java:140)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox.(SelectBox.java:71)
>     at com.me.Terminum.Screens.MainMenu.ShowVideo(MainMenu.java:171)    at
>   com.me.Terminum.Screens.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:121)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)     at
>   com.me.Terminum.Screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:88)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)     at
>   com.me.Terminum.App.create(App.java:13)   at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

I checked it on libgdx 0.9.8 and 0.9.9. What am I do wrong?

Comment: With 0.9.9 and using the `Skin` constructor instead of the `SelectBoxStyle` one, this works fine for me. But the Skin constructor actually delegates to the one with SelectBoxStyle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
Everything that is not marked as optional must be populated. And additionaly, ScrollPaneStyle.background must be filled (even is it marked as optional). Without this, libgdx threw me an exception.